# How to give space in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a response where I have an Image in that response and after every response I need to give a space.How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("#thumbnail").append(response)
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $("#thumbnail").append(response +'&nbsp;')
</script>
```

Comment: Eugh. In 99 out of 100 times, a non-breaking space is a dirty hack and not the right solution.

Comment: Why so?, would you please let us know.

Comment: Because "space" usually means "margin" or "padding" and not "data"

Comment: And the better way can you explain us

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$("#thumbnail").append(response)
$("#thumbnail").append("&nbsp;");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `&nbsp;` html character? or are you looking to apply a padding or margin?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of space you want.

Determine what markup and styling you want. Maybe a literal " ", maybe a [margin](http://www.css3.com/css-margin/).

Add the appropriate CSS to your stylesheet, then write JS that adds the appropriate markup.

Answer (score 0):

Using `css`:

```
#thumbnail img {
   margin-right: yourspace;
}
```